# Magento Wrong decimal placement in store view

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7 version.I am working on two store views ,in both of them i am using same currency which is AED .The issue here that the currency format is not identical in both stores view let say if we talk about english store views it showing 1,299.00 AED but in arabic stores view it shwoing  12.99,00 it only happening product detail page and the strange thing is that in arabic store view it loaded with the correct price which 1299 but it change to 12.99,00 all of a sudden.

Can anyone explain to me to what is the cause of this happening and how to resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to lib/zend/locale/data/ar.xml check the decimal positions ,pattern ,column ,group list is upto standard to the currency...

Comment: yes you are real problem solver in decimal point there is "," and in place of goup list there is  ".".
Thanks u make my day